# My app got admob violation of Site Behavior: Navigation and i don't knew why?

Tags: java, android, admob

i received a message blow  from admob telling me that i have put some misguided links in my app.

i tried to look and fix the problems in the app but nothing ,i improve it a little and made sure that every link is true but it's still sanding the same message.

THE MESSAGE:
As stated in our Program policies, sites or apps displaying Google ads should provide substantial and useful information to the user. Users should be able to easily navigate through the site or app to find what products, goods, or services are promised. Examples of misguided navigation include, but are not limited to:

False claims of downloadable or streaming content Linking to content that does not exist Redirecting users to irrelevant and/or misleading webpages Text on a page unrelated to the topic and/or business model of the website.

please if someone familiar with this problem could he or she give me some hints ,i well live the link to the app if someone want to check something or could see something i didn't and thank you .

[link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.salahliverpool.wallpaper)

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: I encountered  the same issue

Comment: Chong Lip Phang  sadly no i didn't  but a soon as i knew the solution i will post it

Comment: @Nicky any solution?

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: Have any of you got the solution?

Comment: @AbdessamadAnhijou can you share how you solved this issue? Thanks

Comment: @AbdessamadAnhijou i have checked your app it is showing ads now, can you please tell me and others who is searching for solution. It will be great if you can help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Originally had banners ads displayed below the toolbar but have already removed that. Only ad I'm showing now is the app open ad which I followed from their guidelines. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: hi sorry i didn't answer  early the answer  was my Target audience and content
i putted all ages on my target audience  when i should have put from 13 and older i hope it fix your problems cause there is other app that this did not work on them thank you

Answer (score 1):

the answer was my Target audience and content i putted all ages on my target audience when i should have put from 13 and older i hope it fix your problems cause there is other apps that this did not work on them thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sometime banner ads cover or overlap the contents of the app. I had same issue and after fixing the banner ads published my app again and issue resolved. So in my opinion check your banner ads and also check any direct link that leads to another app or webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I have received this message twice. As we are not able to communicate with a human being who would explain what exactly are we violating, it took me some time, failed  attempts and luck to finally 'fix' it.

In the first case, under some conditions, I was interpreting the orientation sensors incorrectly and showing the wrong data to users.

In the second case, I was linking to a completely valid web page via http URL. Replacing it with https version fixed the problem.

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your navigation bar seem to link to "Coming Soon" pages.